# Sending Complex Objects, Attachments with ksoap2-Android

Tags: serialization, android-ksoap2

I'm using ksoap2-Android on an Android project to upload a file.  It's not working.

First of all, my wsdl looks like this:

```
<xsd:element name="Op1RequestType">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="date" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="imgFile" 
                type="tns:Attachment"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

And "tns:Attachment" is defined like this:

```
<xsd:complexType name="Attachment">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="file" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
        <xsd:element name="filename" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I'm creating a `SoapSerializationEnvelope` and adding in the property with name `date` and the value as the string representation of the current date.  This works successfully, even if I don't add a file (note the `minOccurs="0"`).  However, when I try to add a file, it fails horribly:

First, I make a representative of the `Attachment` type by creating a `SoapObject` which has the properties `file` and `filename`, of types `byte[].class` and `String.class` respectively.

Then I add these objects to a generic Vector (to represent the multiplicity of the `imgFile` item) and attach the Vector as a property to the envelope.  This creates a SOAP message successfully, and the response from the server raises an exception (because it's an error message, instead of a proper response, because somehow my input isn't good...):

```
WARN/System.err(438): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soapenv:Server' 
faultstring:'org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement imgFile'
faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@4676b8a0
```

Okay, so what am I doing wrong?  Is there a way to see the request SOAP envelope that I am sending?

Comment: I'm sure my web service is working fine, btw.  I've made clients for it with other tools: wsdl2objc for iPhone, wsdl2java for non-Android java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the request SOAP envelope by calling `getRequest()` on the SoapSerializationEnvelope.  This allowed me to see that the vector object actually places each (file, filename) pair into an `<item></item>` tag, which broke the format.  I now am inserting multiple  items in succession as the wsdl demands.